# Does .NET support TLS-PSK?

Tags: .net, ssl

I see that there is a [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) in the .NET framework. Does this stream support [TLS-PSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK)? If yes, how do I set up the preshared key?

If not, is there some other class or library I can use to support TLS-PSK in my .NET application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at SslStream's methods and properties, it doesn't support PSK ciphersuites.

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) supports PSK ciphersuites.